# Tween onStart function issue kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

Is there tween onStart function or similar? I know there is onFinish.
My animation starts by onClick and i want to off onClick till the end of tween animation.

Comment: Is your `onClick` not going to be equivalent to `onStart`?? Just a thought :)

Comment: you are right, but i want something like i have described) Also there is no onPlay tween callback. I tried to use it - it is not called.

Comment: There is onFinish, but no onStart.  Do I understand that you want to disable click until the tween has finished?  If so, in the click event you could tell your object to stop listening for events: myObject.setListening(false).  Then in the onFinish event you could turn the click back on: myObject.setListening(true).